# "Bootstrap Form Input" Next to a Button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

My end goal is to have a button, and a `<select>` dropdown that looks like normal bootstrap input fields to the right of it (so it matches other UI elements on all screen sizes).

```
class="form-control input-md"
```

I want to use the above css on the input so it gets the colors, borders, etc of a bootstrap form input. I DO not want it to take up the entire screen width, have large margins, OR drop to the next line. I fixed that partially with:

```
.my-modified-input {
    margin:0px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

However, the input still jumps to the next line. Is there a way to prevent this without using bootstrap grid? I don't want to use grid because the spacing between the button and the select dropdown becomes too wide without making rows within rows with custom columns for each screen size.

Comment: Can you show the HTML that you have now?

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for looking at this, but user1655 has the right solution. I can't show my html easily because it's a bunch of angular directives, but the gist is waht user165 has in his fiddle. Going to accept his answer in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the form-inline class.

```
<form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">
          Button
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value="">here is your select</option>
        </select>
      </div>

    </form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bjw1gLv2/

Answer (score 1):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class=" col-sm-4" >
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Click me</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-8">
      <select class="form-control">
       <option>1</option>
      </select>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Hope this will hepl you.